C++ Is there a fast Multidimentional Array that allows for different sized Sub-Arrays
I've recently switch from Java to C++ and have noticed a drop in performance when uses the standard library arrays. I wrote the same program in Java and C++ (or at least as similar as I believe I could) to record their runtimes.
Java Code:
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long stime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        double[][] arr = new double[4][];
        arr[0] = new double[5];
        arr[1] = new double[10];
        arr[2] = new double[5];
        arr[3] = new double[8];
        
        for(int l = 0; l < arr.length; l++) {
            for(int i  = 0; i < arr[l].length; i++) {
                arr[l][i] = 1;
            }
        }
        
        for(int t = 0; t < 100000000; t++) {
            for(int l = 0; l < arr.length; l++) {
                for(int i  = 0; i < arr[l].length; i++) {
                    arr[l][i] += t;
                    arr[l][i] *= t;
                    arr[l][i] /= t;
                }
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("time: " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - stime) / 1000.0f));
    }

C++ Code:
int main()
{
    int subarray_sizes[] = {5,10,5,8};

    double** arr = new double*[4];
    arr[0] = new double[subarray_sizes[0]];
    arr[1] = new double[subarray_sizes[1]];
    arr[2] = new double[subarray_sizes[2]];
    arr[3] = new double[subarray_sizes[3]];

    for(int l = 0; l < 4; l++){
        for(int i = 0; i < subarray_sizes[l]; i++){
            arr[l][i] = 1;

        }
    }

    for(int t = 0; t < 100000000; t++){
        for(int l = 0; l < 4; l++){
            for(int i = 0; i < subarray_sizes[l]; i++){
                arr[l][i] += t;
                arr[l][i] *= t;
                arr[l][i] /= t;
            }
        }
    }

    delete[] arr[3];
    delete[] arr[2];
    delete[] arr[1];
    delete[] arr[0];
    delete[] arr;
}

One run of the Java program took 3.125 seconds and the C++ program took 25.372 seconds. I understand this isn't the best way to measure performance, however I doubt this discrepancy in runtimes is due to just random chance.
I've also seen vectors used in place of arrays in many C++ programs so I wrote a program with vectors.
C++ code:
int main()
{
    int subarray_sizes[] = {5,10,5,8};

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> arr(4);
    arr[0].resize(5);
    arr[1].resize(10);
    arr[2].resize(5);
    arr[3].resize(8);

    for(int l = 0; l < arr.size(); l++){
        for(int i = 0; i < arr[l].size(); i++){
            arr[l][i] = 1;

        }
    }

    for(int t = 0; t < 100000000; t++){
        for(int l = 0; l < arr.size(); l++){
            for(int i = 0; i < arr[l].size(); i++){
                arr[l][i] += t;
                arr[l][i] *= t;
                arr[l][i] /= t;
            }
        }
    }
}

However, this gave the worst performance at 46.806 seconds.
In short, I am wondering is there is a data structure in C++ that allows me to have sub-arrays of variable length that has runtime comparable to that of arrays in java.

you need to compile your C++ program in release mode with optimizations enabled! in Visual studio change the Debug dropbox in the toolbar to Release, and in gcc you must compile it with -O3 compile option.

And run the test without a debugger attached

also since you are doing array operations you should enable vectorization, set Enable Enhanced Instruction Set to AVX2 or AVX512 in visual studio and -march=native in gcc, on godbolt the code takes roughly 1.5 seconds with those optimizations enabled.

@AhmedAEK, I use Code::Blocks instead of visual studio, but I compiled with -O3 and yeah the performance is significantly better (~1.7 seconds). Thanks for the help!

Your problem is clearly missing compile flags, but for the question of how to make fast multidimensional arrays with different sizes: Allocate one vector whose size is the sum of all sum-vector sizes. Make a second vector<size_t> with offsets where each sub-vector starts. That avoids allocation costs, improves locality of data for caching, reduces overhead and allows scalar operations over all entries to be done with a single loop that vectorizes well. The same works in Java

Side note: arrays of arrays and vectors of vectors have an inherent penalty from the data not being contiguous. Sometimes this penalty can be very noticeable. To work with a single contiguous block, start with something like what doug does here and work your way up in complexity as circumstances require.

No not just random chance, simply you not knowing how to turn on optimizations for your C++ compiler.

If you change the dynamic array to be one with automatic storage duration (on the stack) a compiler might even notice that your program doesn't have any side effects (like writing to a file) and optimizes everything away so that you are basically just left with a return 0; (see this), which would approximately take 0.0 seconds to run.

For better efficiency, you should design around the size of the processor's data cache. You want to reduce the time your program waits while reloading the data cache.

Change double** arr = new double*[4]; to double* arr[4];.  There's no need to dynamically allocate four pointers.

The difference in performance here is not because of use of std::vector in C++.   It is because Java compilers typically optimise by default, and C++ compilers do not.   To have an "apples with apples" comparison of C++ and Java performance (i.e. both compilers optimising) it is necessary to explicitly enable optimisation when building the C++ version.    While different algorithms and storage approaches (like that mentioned by Homer) will give benefits, they will also give benefits in both Java and C++.

I took your first version verbatim:
$ g++ -O2 foo.cpp -o foo
$ time foo

real    0m0.822s
user    0m0.800s
sys 0m0.005s

As others have suggested, you want optimization turned on. I barely turned on any (the -O2 argument -- that's an oh, not a zero), and I didn't run in an IDE in debug mode. As you can see, I did it from a command line.
I'm on an M2 Mac -- about a 9-month-old machine.
You see -- 8/10ths of a second.
